# Functional equations for spectral zeta function

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, zeta-functions, laplacian

Functional equation in the theory of  zeta functions is one of the important components of this theory.

I am interested to know whether the similar property, having functional equation, for the spectral zeta functions has been studied? 
This might be a search for such a property of the spectral zeta function (for the Laplacian) of spaces with specific symmetries, e.g. symmetric spaces, or homogeneous ones.

Answer (score 2):

The Selberg zeta function for, say compact Riemann surfaces (other results are known but I forget the exact generality), satisfies a functional equation.  This is built out of eigenfunctions of the Laplacian, but perhaps is not what you mean by a "spectral zeta function."

If you mean something like the Minakshisundaram-Pleijel zeta function, then McKean, in his 1972 paper on Selberg's trace formula, that Minakshisundaram-Pleijel and Weil hoped this may have a functional equation, but there were no positive results thus far.  A quick search reveals [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa71/aa7136.pdf) from 1995 which obtains functional equations for the MP zeta function of spheres and real or complex projective spaces, but I didn't find any other cases where a functional equation has been established.